# Reading first N lines from a text file in C

Tags: c, fgets

I am trying to parse some results from a file and read, let us say, the first 2 lines of it in a C program. Here is what I am doing:

```
int i=0;
while (fgets(line_string, line_size, fp) != NULL){
    if (i==0){
        some_variable = ((int) atoi(line_string));
        i++;
    }
    if (i==1){
        some_other_variable = ((int) atoi(line_string));
        i++;
    }
    else{
        break;
    }
}
```

But the problem is **line_string** keeps pointing to the first line of the file and doesn't progress in the while loop. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `if (i == 0) {... i = 1; ...} else if (i == 1) {... i = 2; ...} else {...}` ie mind the **else**s

Comment: yeah it worked. i had no experience with fgets and it seems to be a goofy mistake. should i delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
if (i==0){
    some_variable = ((int) atoi(line_string));
    i++;
}
if (i==1){
```

You'll enter the **two** `if`s the first time round. You need an `else` to tell the compiler to not enter the second `if`, when `i` goes from 0 to 1:

```
if (i==0){
    some_variable = ((int) atoi(line_string));
    i++;
}
else if (i==1){
```

Answer (score 4):

The `else` branch will be executed when `i==0` because `i==1` is false then.

You may want to add one more `else`.

```
int i=0;
while (fgets(line_string, line_size, fp) != NULL){
    if (i==0){
        some_variable = ((int) atoi(line_string));
        i++;
    }
    else if (i==1){ /* add "else" here */
        some_other_variable = ((int) atoi(line_string));
        i++;
    }
    else{
        break;
    }
}
```